# Angular - Not all code paths return a value (parameter) event: HttpEvent<unknown>

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I'm trying to import data with this code:

```
onFileChange(event) {
  if (this.error !== '') {
    this.error = '';
  }
  if (this.success !== '') {
    this.success = '';
  }
  this.file = event.target.files;
}

onSubmit() {
 this.error = '';
 this.progress = '';
 this.loading = 'loading';

 const file: File = this.file[0];

 return this.importService.importData(file)
  .subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        this.progress = `File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        return this.success = 'Successfully Uploaded your payroll';
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      return this.error = err.error.message;
    }, () => {
      return this.success = 'Uploaded Successfully Done';
    });
}
```

Then I got this error:

> Not all code paths return a value (parameter) event: HttpEvent unknown

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

event is highlighted in this line:

> subscribe(event => {

and

> event.total

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: The if is not returning anything? else if is, but not the if.

Comment: @R.Richards - How do you mean? I added return this.progress, the error is still there

Comment: @R.Richards - I did this:   return this.progress = `File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;   and yet,   .subscribe(event => {   ( error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.)       and    event.total)   are highlighted.       (Object is possibly 'undefined'.)

Comment: .subscribe((event: HttpEvent) => {

Comment: Try writing your `return something` statement after `if...else if` block, since `else` statement is not there, all conditions are not returning something.

Comment: @MikeOne - After added .subscribe((event:HttpEvent) => {     This error comes up:        Not all code paths return a value     Generic type 'HttpEvent' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
(alias) type HttpEvent<T> = HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<T> | HttpProgressEvent | HttpUserEvent<T>
import HttpEvent

Comment: Depending on what the thing is..? I guess HttpEvent<HttpResponse> could work in this case. I’m on mobile so not in a position to check.

Comment: @user11352561 this is a simple error just you need to make sure your methods returns a value. you have `if and else if`. What about none of them don't satisfied? after those condition use `return` and the errors must be disappear

Comment: @user11352561 If your problem has not been resolved yet, create `stackblitz` sample to fixed the problem for you

Comment: this.importService.importData - is this always returning a value? if you type the return value for methods and you have a good IDE, your IDE should flag the problem